# How do i change css style based on js get request status?

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my website, I have several links as my table of content

```
<li><a href="something-ch-1.html">Ch. 1 - TitleHere</a></li>
<li><a href="something-ch-2.html">Ch. 2 - TitleHere</a></li>
<li><a href="something-ch-3.html">Ch. 3 - TitleHere</a></li>
```

I want to send get request (using js) to those anchor texts for checking whether the link inside 404 not found or 200 ok. and if it is 404 not found, I want its style to change. Let just assume its style to change in color.

how do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: so sorry. at first I don't know where to start my code. but from the answer below now I'm sure what I just looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using JS fetch. But first you have to use selector to get value of the `href` attribute. Then `forEach` of them, you may want to create a `fetch` request and get a response. With returned `response.status` attribute, you can continue to next step. More information about fetch can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/status)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the given link using ajax in window.onload. Check the corresponding request and configure style according to it.